# Get emails based on second table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not too good in mysql and for advanced users it's just one minute. I need only emails from table "users" . Every user has table "profiles" or in other way, every "profiles" entry has user_id. Profiles has also "age" entry. I need emails from users which "age" is >= 40.

```
SELECT email FROM users WHERE ... ( age from "profiles" table for that user_id >= 40 )
```

Comment: Please show the schemes for the tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `user_id` of "profiles" table is a foreign key referencing a primary key `id` in "users" table, you can do:

```
SELECT U.email FROM users U, profiles P WHERE P.user_id = U.id AND P.age >= 40
```